# Tinymce Plugin Rendering Source Code With Form Results

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am using Tinymce in a textarea form field to add 'Rich text Editing' to the field. (Form Method = POST).

I used this tutorial to install the files.

In the form itself.. the editor works great.

However....

ISSUE: When my form results are produced, the results include the raw text and source code, instead of the formatted text.

Obviously... the Tinymce plugin has several files and folders. But....

If anyone has experience with the Tinymce plugin, perhaps I am making a rookie, generic, first time error???

Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my php, I just had to remove htmlspecialchars